# pecl install intl gives no releases available?

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl, intl

I'm using mac and xampp and trying to install php package intl for using phpdocumentor as required.
I follow this instruction to install:
[Installing Intl package on your mac with xampp](http://www.phpzce.com/blog/view/15/installing-intl-package-on-your-mac-with-xampp)

But when I was trying to install intl with pecl, it gave me error:

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"
install failed
```

I have searched for solution and try to upgrade pear/pecl but it turned to "unsupported protocol". I also tried to changes /PEAR/REST.php as one solution but it also didn't work. Did anyone face the same problem and solved. Can you help me T_T

Comment: run "pecl install -vvv intl" and post the output.

Comment: or even pecl -vvv install intl

Comment: I have tried many ways/solutions online but problem can't be solved. I decided not to use this

Comment: @HàLink so what are you using? did you get it done?

Comment: Sadly that I haven't done it and forgot it for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Probably some problem with old channels and/or old protocols.

First look at the log (as cweiske said).

```
pecl -vvv install intl
```

Then you can simply try to upgrade PEAR, PECL and update channels

```
pear upgrade
pecl upgrade
pecl channel-update
```

And install intl again

```
pecl install intl
```

Comment: Your solution helped me, however I used `pear channel-update pear.php.net` and `pecl channel-update ppecl.php.net`

Comment: Your answer didn't solve my problem, but with `-vvv` I could realise the *.php.net SSL certificate has just expired: https://imgur.com/DZ5hU7g. Unbelievable.